# How to Update node version in existing serverless project

Tags: node.js, serverless-framework

my serverless project use runtime: nodejs8.10.
How can i update latest version of node in my project?

Comment: how about simply specifying  runtime: nodejs12.x in serverless.yml?

Comment: did you upgrade it properly?

Answer (score 8):

Inside your `serverless.yml` file there is a `provider` block, which includes a `runtime` argument. To move to nodejs12, you just need to declare it and deploy your service.

Example:

```
# serverless.yml

service: my-great-service

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
```

Here is the full [documentation](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/services#serverlessyml)

Comment: once i had upgraded to nodejs16.x all my lambda functions are coming greater than 100MB hence returning with this error Resource handler returned message: "Unzipped size must be smaller than 262144000 bytes